# reactjs - How to display company name only once and show all changed facilities in other rows

Tags: javascript, loops, reactjs, reactive-programming

I find a bug in my existing application. I am trying to render my facilities table where i want to show facility's company name once at top if there is any change.

This code work fines for me if i remove (i===0) but the problem is that it repeats company name at top of each new facility within company. But now i use i===0 and it works fine if i only change first time the first facility in company detail and then change any other facility. I never show me company name if i start changing any facility except the first as my i value changed from 0 to something else. Any idea how can i fix it and come out from my problem.

```
{companies.map((company,i) =>
    company.facilityGroups.map((group,i) => {
      let facilityNo = 0 
      return grp.facilities.map((fac,j) => {
        const existinglimitInFacilityCurrency = fac.existingFacility.limitInFacilityCurrency
        const proposedlimitInFacilityCurrency = fac.proposedFacility.limitInFacilityCurrency

        const facilityJustAdded = !existinglimitInFacilityCurrency && proposedlimitInFacilityCurrency
        const facilityHasProposedChanges = ((existinglimitInFacilityCurrency && proposedlimitInFacilityCurrency) &&
            (existinglimitInFacilityCurrency.amount !== proposedlimitInFacilityCurrency.amount))
            || !!facilityJustAdded
        if(facilityHasProposedChanges) facilityNo++

        return (
          <tbody key={j}>
            {i===0 && facilityNo===1 && facilityHasProposedChanges ? (()=>{
              return(
                <tr className="table__tr--subheading">
                  <td colSpan="7">{company.companyName}</td>
                </tr>)
            })() : null}
            {facilityHasProposedChanges ? (() => {
              return(
                <tr>
                  <td>{fac.description}</td>
                  <td>
                  ....
                </tr>)
            })() : null}
          </tbody>
        )
      })
    })
  )}
```

I have also attached the image how the output appears..
[How it is working now..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHchM.png)

[How i want it to work..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWfxV.png)

Comment: I remove some of code but i hope the logic is clear in existing code. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Just a note: `<tbody key={i,j}>` is the same as `<tbody key={j}>` (it [transpiles to `React.createElement("tbody", { key: (i, j) });`](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=react%2Cstage-3&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=%3Ctbody%20key%3D%7Bi%2Cj%7D%3E%3C%2Ftbody%3E&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true), and `(i, j)` evaluates to the value of `j`). You'll need to come up with something else if you want to use two values as a key, e.g. ``key={`${i},${j}`}``.

Comment: You are right. i have just corrected with what i have in my existing code. i was trying to use both i, and j But good idea to try with it. Anyother suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. I just moved the variable  ( let facilityNo = 0 ) outside of the loops and it fixed my problem. now my code look like this.

```
{companies.map((company,i) => {
  let facilityNo = 0 
  return (
  company.facilityGroups.map((group,i) => {
    return grp.facilities.map((fac,j) => {
      const existinglimitInFacilityCurrency = fac.existingFacility.limitInFacilityCurrency
      const proposedlimitInFacilityCurrency = fac.proposedFacility.limitInFacilityCurrency

      const facilityJustAdded = !existinglimitInFacilityCurrency && proposedlimitInFacilityCurrency
      const facilityHasProposedChanges = ((existinglimitInFacilityCurrency && proposedlimitInFacilityCurrency) &&
        (existinglimitInFacilityCurrency.amount !== proposedlimitInFacilityCurrency.amount))
        || !!facilityJustAdded
      if(facilityHasProposedChanges) facilityNo++

      return (
      <tbody key={j}>
        {facilityNo===1 && facilityHasProposedChanges ? (()=>{
          return(
            <tr className="table__tr--subheading">
              <td colSpan="7">{company.companyName}</td>
            </tr>)
        })() : null}
        {facilityHasProposedChanges ? (() => {
          return(
            <tr>
              <td>{fac.description}</td>
              <td>
              ....
            </tr>)
        })() : null}
      </tbody>
      )
    })
   })
  )}
)}
```